# Adding custom keyboard layout to Xubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, keyboard-layout, xfce

I'm trying to add [workman-p](http://www.workmanlayout.com/blog/) layout to Xubuntu. It comes with several otions to install. There are files for `xorg`, `xmodmap`, and `*.kmap` files.

From [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto:%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions) article I found out that you need to add keymaps to `/etc/X11/xkb/symbols/`, and that all the layout files should be there, but I didn't even have the directory. So I added it, copied the files there but it didn't help in any way. I guess xfce doesn't use this folder in 13.10.

I had some success with xmodmap but it just changed my layout and turned off the switching to Russian I have set up.

I need a way to add layout so that it can be switched in a normal way i.e. the settings menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Xkb directory is located at `/usr/share/X11/xkb`
Besides, it's not XFCE that uses the directory, it's Xkb, a part of Xorg.
To create a new layout just create a file in `symbols/` (eg `asdf`). After that you can switch to the newly created layout with `setxkbmap asdf`

Next step would be to register the layout, see the files `rules/base.xml` and `rules/evdev.xml`.
After registering you can switch to it other than by calling `setxkbmap` directly: most desktop environments honor those files and all keyboard layouts you see in keyboard settings are actually from those XML files.

Comment: How do you register it?