# How can I activate a custom keyboard layout

Tags: 13.10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, system-settings

I have defined a custom keyboard layout following this description: [Custom keyboard layout definitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto%3A%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions)

The layout definition is added to this file: `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` and it starts like this:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "usintde" {

  name[Group1]= "English (US, alternative international and German)";
  include "us"
```

I can use it on the command line using `setxkbmap 'us(usintde)'`.
However, in Ubuntu 13.10, I can not choose it from the Unity settings menus. I tried settings > text input and then clicked on the + sign, but none of the layouts is named like mine (also after new login and restart).

How can I activate this customly defined layout (and then use it in the layout switcher)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading a similar question ([Adding custom keyboard layout to Xubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425921/adding-custom-keyboard-layout-to-xubuntu-13-10)), this [page](http://simos.info/blog/archives/1134) showed me the answer: I have to edit the evdev.xml and base.xml files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules`, adding a variant snippet, too.

This is nicely described there. Just one more caveat: Use `setxkbmap '<file>(<yourvariant>)'` (for the example in the question: `setxkbmap 'us(usintde)'`) to test your layout and to make sure that you can log in again.

Sorry for this duplicate. I read many similarly named questions and answers which only treated the symbols/xy files and old versions of the unity settings. I found this one too late.